# Doing a Count on more than a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following tables:

```
**Product**  
ProdID  int  
ProdOwner (nvarchar)  
Views int  


**Reviews**  
RevID int  
RevDate datetime  
ProdOwner  
ProdID
```

If I pass a string like "Jake Bill" (ProdOwner) to my storedproc, I need to get the following output

```
Total Products Owned: 27  
Total Product Views: 78967  
Total Reviews Received on All Products: 89
```

How can I write this query? I am using SQL 2008. This is what I did:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProdCountByOwner]  
(  
   @ProdOwnerName    nvarchar(256)
)  
AS  
SET NOCOUNT ON  

SELECT COUNT(p.ProdID),  Count(p.Views), Count(r.RevID)  FROM Product p join Review r
on p.ProdID = r.ProdID
WHERE p.ProdOwner = @ProdOwnerName
GO
```

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag it as such if it is...

Comment: no homework..i have added now with what I did so far

Comment: Need some sample data. Count(p.Views) makes no sense for a product

Comment: You say you are using SQL [Server] 2008, and yet you've tagged the question with the `sql-server-2005` tag.

Comment: I have changed tag to sql2008..still getting used to this forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Total Products Owned],
    SUM(p.Views) AS [Total Product Views],
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM Product p JOIN Reviews r ON p.ProdID = r.ProdID
      WHERE p.ProdOwner = 'Jake Bill'
    ) AS [Total Reviews Received on All Products]
FROM Product p
WHERE p.ProdOwner = 'Jake Bill'
```

Comment: thanks! your query is spoton..Any way to optimize this on a table containing 20000 rows or there is no need?

Comment: @gorgeous Assuming `Reviews.ProdID` is already indexes... Try adding a index on `Product.ProdOwner`

Comment: @gorgeous: I would compare this wih my solution. Mine will avoid a corrleated count. 20k rows is a rounding error too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting too high results (that is, the highest count is given for all 3)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProdID),  SUM(p.Views), Count(DISTINCT r.RevID)
FROM
    Product p LEFT join Review r on p.ProdID = r.ProdID
WHERE
    p.ProdOwner = @ProdOwnerName
```